# HBaseWriteStreamExample, but no HBaseReadStreamExample in Flink docs

Tags: hbase, apache-flink, flink-streaming

Why is there no HBaseReadStreamExample in the [Flink-HBase connector](https://github.com/citlab/flink-realtime-streaming/tree/master/flink-staging/flink-hbase/src/test/java/org/apache/flink/addons/hbase/example)?

There seems to be a Read, Write, and WriteStream example, but no ReadStream.

Is stream reading from HBase into Flink a bad practice?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a fairly common limitation when it comes to connecting databases to stream processors. On the one hand, it is straightforward to implement writing a stream to a database. This might simply involve a series of INSERTs, or UPSERTS, for example. On the other hand, implementing a general purpose stream reader for a database involves ingesting the database's change data capture stream, which is much more complex to implement.

Note that the [HBase connector](https://ci.apache.org/projects/flink/flink-docs-stable/dev/table/connect.html#hbase-connector) will support being used as a lookup source in Flink 1.11.

Also note that better integration between HBase and Flink is planned, for example, see [FLIP-117](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/FLINK/FLIP-117%3A+HBase+catalog).